# Microsoft Graph API Retrieving Resource Mailbox Attributes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to fetch information about meeting rooms such as capacity and office.

I have the resource email address and MS ID.

I can view this information in Outlook but cannot when using the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{resource id}`

Is this possible using the current API?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add one more attribute in graph endpoint to fetch room details as mentioned in the below example :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{resource id}/findrooms
```

**Reference** : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findrooms

Comment: Thanks for the response - this only gives me a list of meeting rooms with their name and email address. I'm looking for additional properties such as capacity

Comment: Also, `v1.0` should be `beta` instead :)

Comment: sorry, even I was using beta version. check the updated one.

Comment: I'm afraid this information isn't available through Microsoft Graph at the moment.

Comment: The answer I was hoping not to get... thank you anyway!